# Custom .bst style and reformatting \cite entries

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing

I have created a custom `.bst` file with makebst. I managed to reformat the thebibliography-environment entries look by editing the .bst file by hand. This wasn't a hard task.

But, now I would like to reformat the look of the `\cite[]{}`-entries in the actual text.

I am using `csquotes` package and managed to change the look of `\textquote` entries with:

```
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{~\rm \small #1}

\textquote[{\cite[1]{Foobar01}}]{Blah Blah.}
```

But when I use ordinary cites:

```
Blah blah.\cite[1]{Foobar01}
```

I can't find a part in the `.bst` file that defines how these are formatted. Also I could not find a parameter in the csquotes package that would change the format of all cites, as `\cite` is not a csquote command.

I could go around this problem by using `\textquote` everywhere, but I feel that it's semantically incorrect. After all, citations are NOT quotes.

So I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how I can reformat the look of `\cite` entries even in documents that don't use `csquotes` or other packages, just a custom `.bst` style.

Edit:

I am not using `cite` nor `natbib` packages.

My `\cite` entries are formatted as [Foo01] or [Foo01, 15-39] with page numbers in the PDF. All I want to do is to change their formatting, not contents. I would like all `\cite` to appear in the final PDF with a certain font size (for example with size `\tiny` and with color red).

With `csquotes` I was able to do `\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{~\rm \small #1}` which changed all `csquotes` cites into small roman font.

What would be the way to format all normal `\cite` in a similar way?

If this is not enough I'm not sure if I understand what kind of additional information you need.

Comment: @user1942: Please provide more information. Do you use packages like `cite` or `natbib`? What is the general citation style you're using (numeric, author-year, ...)? How should the different parts of the `\cite`-output (numeral, author name, year, page numbers) be reformatted? (A complete example would be even better.)

Comment: @user1942: The .bst file does not affect how `\cite` works, so as lockstep says we need more detail on what output you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to changing the formatting of a part of a document is to save the original macro and then create a new definition. In this case, you might try

```
\let\OrgiCite\cite
\renewcommand*\cite[2][]{%
  {%
    \tiny
    \color{red}%
    \OrigCite[#1]{#2}%
  }%
}
```

Here, I've grabbed both of the arguments for the `\cite` macro, and then set up the text formatting before using the 'real' `\cite` to do the actual citation. I'd point out that this will work if you do switch to something like the [`cite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package for superscript citations. However, you say that you are not doing that, so hopefully it will work.

Comment: I'd point out that while this should work, I'm not really sure _why_ you want to do these odd things with your citations. The usual requirements are superscripts or hyperlinks, which can be handled using the `cite` and `hyperref` packages, respectively.

Comment: I've used it merely as typographic sugar for more appealing citation markings (colors, oldstyle numbers etc.).