# Customize citation style

Tags: citing

Is it possible to customize citation styles? I'm not talking about the bibliography, but the appearance of the optional argument in \cite[Theorem $4$]{Pitagora}.

Usually it is rendered as [Pit03, Theorem 4], but one may want to have [Pit03], Theorem 4 or Theorem 4 - [Pit03] or whatever. Does the bibliography style change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5484/custom-bst-style-and-reformatting-cite-entries).

For your specific example, you could also just define your own command

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{\cite{#1},~#2}
```

And then cite it using `\mycite{Pitagora}{Theorem~4}`. I would not put `$` in the reference, since the `4` is not a mathematical formula and should be treated as text.

Comment: I don't want to change all \cite to \mycite, but using a temporary command to make the rename, as suggested in the thread you link, works fine. Thank you