# Customizing citation style

Tags: citing

A quick follow-up to question to [Customize citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/customize-citation-style), basically.

Right now I am defining a custom command like this

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\cite{#1}}
```

How should I modify it to produce an output like "[1.]"? It should also work with multiple arguments and then output "[1, 2, 3.]". Or if not modifying the command presented, would an easier way exist?

Comment: You don't want to modify the cite command: you want to modify the bibliography style... Are you using bibtex or biblatex?

Comment: @Seamus bibtex, I believe. However, is it a problem that I need the styles I described in my post **in addition** to the usual citing styles. This meaning that sometimes I'd want to have "[1]" and sometimes "[1.]"

Comment: Patching into the cite command like that couldn't even be done by `makebst`. I think a biblatex solution might be forthcoming, but otherwise it might be tricky. If you can find a cite command that is without parentheses, it would be easy, actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some clue about what bibliography style you're using I'm not sure how much can be usefully said about your question.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have `\cite` that produces `[1]` and `\mycite` that produces `[1.]`. I don't think you can do this straightforwardly by patching `\cite` in this way.

If you switched to a bibliography style where `\cite` just produced `1`, then you could easily define:

```
\newcommand\mycite[1]{[\cite{#1}]}
\newcommand\mydotcite[1]{[\cite{#1}.]}
```

Comment: Actually I pretty much did what you suggested. By using natbib, I defined the citations to look like "1" and added a few commands. Works atleast and I'm able to get my work done, thanks!

Comment: @Jay good glad it helped. I actually had a look for styles that just print `1` but I couldn't find any. I didn't look at natbib though. I always associate it with authoy (year) styles...